# FSL reallignment for some Brain maps

Tags: image-processing, imaging, medical, neuroscience

I have all these Dicom files of some patients brain maps. I sorted them by patient, map, b_value and slice.
Every slice of the brain has 15 gradients dicom files, a 'b zero' dicom file, and a 'b_x' isotropic dicom file (which my teacher said it's useless for what I need to do).
Now I have to do on them some DTI analysis, since my teacher asked me to convert them in .nii files and correct them with FSL, doing a Eddy current correction, and then I should 'reallign' each of the 15 gradients in every slice  to its b_zero. Do you know how I can do this last thing (the 'reallignation') with FSL?
Also, should I do the Eddy current correction before or after the reallignation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you supposed to do this using existing software or write new software?  If existing software, this question would be off-topic for this site.  If new software, then you need to narrow this down a lot to a specific question about algorithms for aligning images (for example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't help you, but you will probably find the answer in the FSL docs: http://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/

If you want to use FSL from your own code, try NiPy (Neuroimaging in Python): http://nipy.sourceforge.net/nipype/users/interface_tutorial.html